# WSO2 APIM unable to create an access token from the store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have an WSO2 APIM deployment (2.0.0) behind some proxy servers. When creating an application or generating an access token from the store we've got a following exception:

```
 ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil} -  Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient. {o
rg.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while calling token endpoint: HTTP error code : 301
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:367)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistra
tionWorkflowExecutor.java:151)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrati
onWorkflowExecutor.java:118)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.jav
a:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java
:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2789)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:385)

...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while calling token endpoint: HTTP error code : 301
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.getNewApplicationAccessToken(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:367)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistra
```

what I assume is that some of the proxy services (we may have not direct control over) returns HTTP 301 when generating a token.

I wanted to see what URL is really called  with what data from AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl and check what is really returned.

I am unable to locate the AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl or APIStoreHostObject neither find what endpoint is really called.

Thank you for any hint / advice

**Edit:**

I found the implementation [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/core/impl/DefaultKeyManagerImpl.java) though it's in different package (newer version?).

Endpoint is retrieved here:

```
String tokenEndpoint = 
ServiceReferenceHolder.getInstance().getAPIMConfiguration()
   .getKeyManagerConfigs().getTokenEndpoint();
```

though don't know how the endpoint is computed (APIKeyManager section is commented you assuming using the local /self service, it's working on another environment)

The exception is experienced when generating application key or application access token, here is the [stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/yygBrPaM).

I see possible 301 response when a client would call an HTTP endpoint, though I see only https config everywhere

```
<RevokeAPIURL>https://api.xxxxxx:443/api/revoke</RevokeAPIURL>
```

where /api is mapped on the proxy server to the axis2 http port if the gateway

**Resolution:**

The token endpoint is derived from RevokeAPIURL parameter (if a separate KeyManager is not defined, replacing "revoke" with "token" string). The implementation sends a proper HTTP(S) request to the endpoint with the Host header. The issue was on the proxy service configuration routing incorrectly when the host header is used

Comment: The correct class is https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.0.4/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java

Comment: `APIM 2.0.0` git tag is `v6.0.4`. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.0.4

Comment: @Bhathiya thank you, I will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you configure revoke url properly in `api-manager.xml`

```
<RevokeAPIURL>https://${GATEWAY_SERVER_HOST}:{port}/revoke</RevokeAPIURL>
```

You can put real values for `${GATEWAY_SERVER_HOST}` and `{port}`.

Comment: the *RevokeAPIURL* is well defined and accessible from outside :/

Comment: I just saw that you've said create application also fails. can you post logs for that?

Comment: It is the log for creating the application. The top stacktrace is diffferent, but I see the cause is getNewApplicationAccessToken as well. I will post the whole stacktrace

Comment: Can you invoke `https://api.xxxxxx:443/api/token` and generate a new token?

Comment: indeed, a token is nicely generated.  I even considered SNI (multiple SSL certificates) as a factor, but if that would be an issue, we would get SSL exception, not 301.

Comment: I see configs in different stage environments (DEV, ACC) are very similar and one of them works. That's why I assume there's something misconfigured on a proxy endpoint. But I am unable to locate what is really called. I assume the AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl  calls the token endpoint , just I still have to find where it gets back the 301 response from

Comment: the issue is found on the proxy routing as expected. Regardless that I'm givving you the credit, because indeed the RevokeAPIURL parameter is used to derive the token url as well.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [blog](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.in/2016/05/fix-wso2-api-manager-token-generation.html). Also make sure you don't have any repeated records which violates the constraints. This mostly happens while migrating wso2-am from 1.9.0 to 2.1.0.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Though the problem was already solved - the `revoke` endpoint was inaccessible due to the reverse proxy settings